# Should I use sed, awk, perl, for altering text spanning multiple lines and selecting only the info needed?

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I'm working on a project for class where we take a file full of lines describing classes like the one below

> CSC 1010 - COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS
>   Computers and Applications. Prerequisite: high school Algebra II. History of computers, >hardware components, operating systems, applications software, data communication.
>   3.000 Credit hours

and turn it into

> CSC1010,COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS,3

I used:

```
sed -n 's/^CSC /CSC/p' courses.txt > practice.txt
```

which outputs:

> CSC1010 - COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS
>   CSC1310 - INTRO COMP PROGRAMMING NON-MAJ
>   CSC2010 - INTRO TO COMPUTER SCIENCE
>   CSC2310 - PRIN OF COMPUTER PROGRAMMING
>   CSC2320 - FUND OF WEBSITE DEVELOPMENT
>   CSC2510 - THEOR FOUNDATIONS OF COMP SCI
>   CSC3010 - HISTORY OF COMPUTING
>   CSC3210 - COMPUTER ORG & PROGRAMMING
>   CSC3320 - SYSTEM-LEVEL PROGRAMMING
>   CSC3330 - C++ PROGRAMMING
>   CSC3410 - DATA STRUCTURES-CTW
>   CSC4110 - EMBEDDED SYSTEMS
>   CSC4120 - INTRODUCTION TO ROBOTICS

and I also used:

```
sed '/\.000 Course hours//p' courses.txt > courses10.txt
```

which outputs:

> 3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   4
>   4
>   4
>   4
>   4

My problem is trying to select whether the sed, awk, or perl would be better. So, far I've used sed to eliminate the lines that are not composed either of the course title or the number of credit hours. As you saw above. I was hoping to use a regular expression to sort through the file and get each line that started with "CSC" or contained ".000 Course hours". I figured that after I got that output I could use a command in the sed to remove the new line from the end of the lines starting with the CSC and replace that with a comma. After that I would replace the backslash with a comma. However, to do that I think I would need to use an extended expression so sed would probably be out. The regular expression I was considering using is `(^CSC |[0-9]\.000)`. So, should I be doing this in sed, awk, or perl. If you could please include your reasoning as to why it would be more efficient to use whatever method you suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'll try again to add the code I used. As I said before though it kept giving me errors when I tried to submit the questions.

Comment: which you *you* be doing this with?  whichever you like.  try them all and then you tell us.  any will work, and most people would choose based on what they are most familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  print if s/^CSC\s+/CSC/ and s/\s+-\s+/,/;
  printf ",%.0f\n", $1 if /^([\d.]+)\s+Credit hours/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `awk` because you want to match and reformat lines and `awk` is perfect for this:

```
/CSC/ {                 # Lines that match CSC
    split($0,a,"- ")    # Split the line around the hyphen and following space
    gsub(/ /,"",a[1])   # Remove the spaces from the first part of the split
    printf a[1]","a[2]  # Print the line in required format
}
/Credit hours/ {        # Lines that match Credit hours
    printf ",%i\n",$1   # Print the integer value of credit hours  
}
```

Demo:

```
awk '/CSC/{split($0,a,"- ");gsub(/ /,"",a[1]);printf a[1]","a[2]}/Credit hours/{printf ",%i\n",$1}' file
CSC1010,COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS,3
```

I prefer `awk` to `Perl`, which has no advantage (or disadvantage) for this. Using `sed` would be a regexp hack so I'd stay away from a `sed` solution.