# Print two awk matches on one line

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to make a bash script for an assignment that matches certain text fields and prints them in a certain format. I'm trying to get the course number, title, and number of credit hours (converted from decimal to integer) and output it to a file called `course_list`.

Sample input:

```
CSC 1010 - COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS
Computers and Applications. Prerequisite: high school Algebra II. History of computers, hardware components, operating systems, application software, data communication. 
3.000 Credit hours
```

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '/CSC/ {print $1$2","$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9} /[0-9].(000)/ {print substr(","$1,1,2)}' courses.txt | cat >> course_list
```

Here's the output I get:

```
CSC1010,COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS   
,3
```

Here's the output I want:

```
CSC1010,COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS,3
```

I'm thinking that I'm pretty close but I cannot figure out how to print the two separate matches without the `\n`.

Comment: This: `| cat >> course_list` is just hilarious: you're piping the output to a program which writes what it receives, then redirecting it to a file.  Just omit the `| cat` part and it does the same thing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use sed, awk, perl, for altering text spanning multiple lines and selecting only the info needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188904/should-i-use-sed-awk-perl-for-altering-text-spanning-multiple-lines-and-selec)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
CSC 1010 - COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS
Computers and Applications. Prerequisite: high school Algebra II. History of computers, hardware components, operating systems, application software, data communication.
3.000 Credit hours

$ awk '/CSC/{split($0,a,/ - /); gsub(/ /,"",a[1])} /[0-9].000/{printf "%s,%s,%d\n",a[1],a[2],$1}' file
CSC1010,COMPUTERS & APPLICATIONS,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 's/CSC[^-]*-[ ]*\([^\.]*\).*\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.000[ ]*Credit.*/\1,\2/p' input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1$2","$4,$5,$6","$(NF-2)}' RS= course_list
```

**Explanation:**

`NF` is an internal variable which stores number of fields. `$NF` holds the value of the last field. Since OP wants to capture course hours which is at `NF-2` position, we print that.

Comment: I the parameters `RS=` was left out, no?

Comment: conversion of the credit hours number to an integer was left out too and it'd fail when the course title is other than 3 words and it'd fail when there's more than just those 3 lines in the file. I assume all of that is the case in the OPs real input or there'd be no point writing a script.

Answer (score 0):

@Powdercake, yes that is close. Just change `{print substr(","$1,1,2)}` to `{print $1+0}` to force `$1` into (default) numerical format (and leave out the pipe and cat things like @John Zwinck mentioned)